# Is it possible to change app logo like Calendar app?

Tags: ios

I was wondering if it is possible to have an app logo which could be different every day like a Calendar app logo changes according to date changes.

Comment: I don't believe so and have never seen any app with that. When using Xcode it allows you to only upload 1 icon.
Also there is nothing said in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not. Only Apple has access to that. You could probably do it on jailbroken devices, but not on regular ones. There is not API to do that.